# Haskell basic factorial not exiting?

Tags: haskell, factorial

I'm learning Haskell, and am having trouble with a basic factorial function from [this tutorial](http://learnyouahaskell.com/syntax-in-functions).

Basically, I've defined a factorial as such:

```
Prelude> let factorial 0 = 1
Prelude> let factorial n = n * factorial (n - 1)
```

The type checks out:

```
Prelude> :t factorial
factorial :: Num a => a -> a
```

which makes sense. However, the behavior of this function doesn't. It results in `(interactive): out of memory` no matter what the input is.

```
Prelude> factorial 5
(interactive): out of memory
```

I have to assume this is an infinite recursive call leading to an out of memory error, but I'm not sure what could possibly be causing it. The same thing happens with `factorial 0`, even though I've explicitly declared this to be 1:

```
Prelude> factorial 0
(interactive): out of memory
```

Now, here's the weird part: If I define the factorial function in a file, it works fine. I create a file `tesths.hs` s.t.:

```
factorial 0 = 1
factorial n = n * factorial (n - 1)
```

Then, if I go back to GHCI and run `:l tesths.hs`, I can execute `factorial 5` without error.

What's going on here?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Two functions were defined, rather than a single function with two cases.  Try the same commands having first run `:set -Wall`, and you should get a name shadowing warning.  To solve the problem, try

```
let factorial 0 = 1; factorial n = n * factorial (n - 1)
```

instead.

Comment: Huh. Makes sense, I suppose. That's strange behavior, though.

Comment: It is.  `let ...` in ghci is really `let ... in`.  This is definitely not the only thing a little odd about ghci - a result is shown differently depending on if its of type `Show a => a`, `Show a => IO a`, or `IO ()`.

Comment: That makes a bit of sense. It's dependent upon the type of input, which is needed in almost any language

Answer (score 12):

You can also use the `:{ ... :}` syntax to give multi-line input:

```
Prelude> :{
Prelude| let factorial 0 = 1
Prelude|     factorial n = n * factorial (n - 1)
Prelude| :}
Prelude> factorial 10
3628800
Prelude>
```

Similarly, you can use multiline mode and indentation with `:set +m`:

```
Prelude> :set +m
Prelude> let factorial 0 = 1
Prelude|     factorial n = n * factorial (n - 1)
Prelude| 
Prelude> factorial 10
3628800
Prelude>
```

Note the blank line.  You can turn multiline mode back off with `:unset +m`.

See [Section 2.4.3 of the GHC User's Guide, "[Using GHCi with] Multiline input"](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.6.2/html/users_guide/interactive-evaluation.html#ghci-multiline) for documentation on this stuff.

Answer (score 4):

Note that there is this pretty one-liner, too:

```
let factorial n = product [1..n]
```

Comment: http://www.willamette.edu/~fruehr/haskell/evolution.html